# Can we develop desktop app with Electron to monitor the remote windows service

Tags: node.js, desktop-application, node-webkit, electron

I was planning to write a desktop app which will monitor the remote and local windows service status, read remote log files and display in the app.

I did search but didn't find any useful information regarding such. 
Is this possible to achieve this goal with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) or node-webkit

if yes can you please suggest the direction.

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS has a built-in module called [OS](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) which can give you information such as the amount of free memory, uptime, network interface etc (have a look at the docs to see all the things you can do with it). These pieces of information can be easily paired with Electron or NW.js to build a monitoring app. You can additionally use the `child_process` lib to build a list of running processes using `child_process.exec('ps -ewwwo %cpu,%mem,comm', function (error, stdout, stderr) {...});`

Comment: Thanks that definitely guided for further